# Adapting the sun rise equation onto the moon

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently a grade 12 student, and as a part of my program we are required to write an "analysis" study on a topic of our choice. I wanted to determine the amount of solar energy that would be able to be generated on the moon, however I have gotten stuck on adapting the sunrise equation which could be used to calculate the amount of sunlight on the earth per day onto the moon.

I don't really have any leads, and any suggestions on how I can proceed would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions.

Comment: maybe the physics site, https://physics.stackexchange.com/  is more suitable to help you with that.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com is probably even better. Don't forget that 1 day on the Moon lasts around a month.